# AWS Call Flow - Collecting Alphabetical Inputs via Voice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

we are attempting to use AWS Call flow to create a certain customer experience. All the examples around customer inputs appear to be numeric data - we are trying to understand how to collect text based data (either via voice or typing) such as the Customer's First and Last Name. Looking for a fairly detailed overview and then how to use those variables later on in the call flow.

Not a ton of detailed examples online.

Reviewed the call flow documentation online but can't find any examples like this.